# Powershell to deploy wsp scoped at web application

Tags: powershell

We have created several wsps and each wsp have 1 or more feature. In test environment we deploy the projects via VS. But, for production we are thinking of doing it the powershell way.

I am new to powershell and started from this [link](http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/using-powershell-to-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-wsp-2/).

```
Add-SPSolution "D:\Deploy\MySharePointSolution.wsp"
Install-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –WebApplication http://myspwebapp –GACDeployment
```

My question is:

There is one wsp with feature scoped at web application level. And above method it install it seems to be targetting the one webapplication URL. I want it to be available for all web applications and not just one URL. Is this possible in powershell?

I want to deploy this WSP to the FARM and not to one particular web application. This way all web apps will be able to activate and use it.

Comment: Always deploy the same way in test and prod #JustSayin :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-AllWebApplications` flag to deploy it to all existing web applications. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534(v=office.15).aspx

Note that Web Apps created afterwards do not automatically have this solution packaged deployed.

Comment: How do I tell the web apps created after deployment to use the wsp?

Comment: You deploy the solution again but this time scope it to the specific web application.

Comment: Suppose the farm has 10 web applications. Then, say I deploy a solution to web app 1, then, is it possible for me to activate this same deployed solution in other 9 web apps without re-deploying?

Comment: Why not use install-spsolution -Identity $solution  -GACDeployment ?

Comment: if the package has resources scoped to a web app, it is required to specify one (or all)